# Pre-1990's sci-fi novel about a man who becomes a legionnaire in a Roman/Romanesque Empire

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

I remember reading it in the late 1980's or early 1990's. If I recall correctly, it was:

- set in the future
- based on the Roman model of civilization and empire
- about a guy who was training to become a legionnaire
- telling the story of his training, deployment, first battles, survival
- about his becoming friends with another warrior
- about the fact that he and his buddy were not originally citizens
- about his becoming a commander
- probably low tech - swords, spears, bows, not guns or lasers
- may have been limited to a single planet

It seems like it was part of a series of at least two books. Maybe the guy eventually becomes emperor.

Stories that I've ruled out:

- Anything after 1998
- David Drake - *Ranks of Bronze*
- Douglas Hill - *Last Legionary*
- Jerry Pournelle - *Janissaries*
- Robert Silverberg - *Roma Eterna*
- Harry Turtledove - *Misplaced Legion*

Comment: The first 2 of those you've ruled out deal with legionaries who use actual swords and shields (well, gladii and scuta); is this also a story about low-tech soldiers?

Comment: It seems like they used swords. I’m gonna edit cuz now that think about it. It might have been limited to a single planet.

Comment: Maybe this one? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169536/story-id-romans-in-space?r=SearchResults

Comment: @DannyMcG Note that series didn't come out until 2003, so it might be too late.  (Besides, I've read those, and at least in the first 3 books there's no low-ranking Roman legionary-type viewpoint character.)

Comment: Except for the galactic empire bit and 1990s it sounds like Cursor's Fury (2006), which is 3rd book in a series of 5. The protagonist is assigned to join a legion, becomes commander by the end of that book and by the end of the series is First Lord.

Comment: Janissaries by Jerry Pournelle. Has a Roman legion training theme: Rick organizes and trains the Tamaerthans to fight more effectively, mingling their exceptional longbowmen with defensive pikemen. He then leads them on a raid on an outpost of the neighboring, powerful empire established by humans kidnapped from ancient Rome during the reign of Septimius Severus. The local Roman governor, Marcellus, attacks with his heavy, cataphract-like cavalry and is soundly defeated by the pike-longbow combination of the Tamaerathans.

Comment: As @DavidW notes, 2000's are too late.

Comment: Probably not the right books, but there is the Atom Gods series by van Vogt comprised of the books "the Empire of the Atom" (1957) and "the Wizard of Linn" (1962).

The main character is part of the "priesthood"/scientists, so likely does not fit the legionnaire training you described.

Comment: Dave Duncan's series 'A handful of Men' might fit. The first volume 'The Cutting Edge' (the only one I've read) came out in 1992. The main character, of the first volume at least, is broken to the ranks (because his family is suddenly out of favour) and serves as a common legionnaire until he gets lucky and saves the legion's standard from falling.

Set in a fantasy world, but very Roman Empire feel, very realistic warfare, and competent writing by Duncan. I suspect I will now read the second volume ...